# ionic chamar function dentro do callback

Tags: javascript, typescript

Estou tentando chamar uma função dentro da outra função porem ele fica dando:

> ERROR ReferenceError: "closeGPS is not defined"
>       enableGPS tab1.page.ts:35

meu codigo atualmente:

```
enableGPS() {
    console.log("enable gps");
    this.gps = true;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (local) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('lat', local.coords.latitude);
        sessionStorage.setItem('lon', local.coords.longitude);
        closeGPS();
    });
}

closeGPS() {
    this.close = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Troque o callback para uma *arrow function* (`() => {}`), dessa forma, o `this` irá referenciar o local em que `closeGPS()` está e, então, chame ela com o `this`

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((local) => {
    sessionStorage.setItem('lat', local.coords.latitude);
    sessionStorage.setItem('lon', local.coords.longitude);
    this.closeGPS();
});
```